# Cómo obtener registros aleatorios, junto con su id MySQL y PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Mi problema es que no puedo ejecutar mi consulta, ya la he probado en *mysql*, uso *phpmyadmin* y si me funciona pero desde mi php no me ejecuta la consulta quiciera saber cual es mi error y si saben una forma mas optima y eficaz por favor necesito de su ayuda. Gracias

**Opción 1: Mi problemas es que no se ejecuta la consulta.**

Hasta ahora esto es lo que tengo: Mi consulta, he leído que esta consulta es lenta con muchos registros, pero yo tengo o lo más que pueda crecer mi tabla es 200 registros así que creo que para mi no me afectaría tanto bueno sino porfa acepto sugerencias, recomendaciones:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM preguntas ORDER BY rand(" . time() . " * " . time() . ") LIMIT '$count[0]'";
$preguntas = mysqli_query($conexion ,$sql);

while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_array($preguntas)){
       array_push ($array_id_preguntas, $registro[0]);
       array_push ($array_preguntas, $registro[1]);
}
```

**Opcion 2: Mi problema es que no puedo obtener el id de la pregunta ya ordenada aleatoriamente.**

Lo segundo que intente fue meterlos en arreglos:

```
include_once('../Verificacion/Conexion/Abrir_Conexion.php') ;
  $consulta = "select * from preguntas";
  $consulta2 = "SELECT COUNT(id_pregunta) from preguntas";

  $consultaPreguntas = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
  $consultaFilas = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta2);
include_once('../Verificacion/Conexion/Cerrar_Conexion.php') ;

$array_id_preguntas = array();
$array_preguntas = array();

while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_array($consultaPreguntas)){
      array_push ($array_id_preguntas, $registro[0]);
      array_push ($array_preguntas, $registro[1]);
}

//Obtengo la cantidad de registros
$count = mysqli_fetch_array($consultaFilas); 

//Obtengo el tamaño del array
$length = sizeof($array_preguntas);

//Mi rango para indicar hasta donde se tomaran los números aleatorios
$pocisiones = range(0,($count[0]-1));
//Se crean los números aleatorios sin repetirse ACLARO
shuffle($pocisiones);

//
```

Se supone que obtengo el número aleatorio y aguardo la pregunta con su respectivo número pero el problemas es cómo saber que el número aleatorio es su id de la pregunta no es eficaz ya que pueden borrar un registro y habría confusión no serían las id de las preguntas.

Así que opto por hacer consultas a la BD y obtener ya aleatoriamente los registros o hacer una consulta grande con todos los registros ejemplo:

```
$query .= "select * from preguntas WHERE id_pregunta = '$pocision'";
```

La ejecuto así:

```
$preguntas = mysqli_query($conexion ,$query);
```

Y creo que esto acumula muchas consultas para después ejecutarlas todas al mismo tiempo pero no se ejecuta me marca error PHP. Que me sugieren o indíquenme mi error porfa.

```
foreach ($pocisiones as $pocision){
array_push($preguntas_aleatorias, $array_preguntas[$pocision]);
array_push($id_preguntas_aleatorias, $pocision);
}
```

Mi error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Qué error te da en la opción 2?

Comment: Que extraño, yo lo pruebo y me funciona normal tu código. Podrias colocar esto en tu código, para ver mas especficiamente el error: var_dump(mysqli_error($conexion));

Colocalo, despues de mysqli_query y tambien despues de mysqli_fetch_array

Comment: Me marca NULL y eso porque?

Comment: @DiegosSánchez en algun punto estas cerrando la conexión antes de hacer la consulta con: mysqli_close($conexion);???

Comment: Cierro la conexión después del ciclo while ó podría mostrarme cómo la tiene usted y le funciona porfa.

Comment: Debe ser un problema con la conexion, por eso da NULL, coloca esto en tu archivo de conexion: if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(); }

Comment: Amigo no se si sea porque vuelvo a abrir mi conexion ya que ise mi consulta directamente desde el principio y funciona. Bueno intentare hacerla funcionar con mi variable $cont ya que es viable tener cuantos registros hay. Gracias a todos por ayudar y si encuentran otra solución porfa publiquenla.

Answer (score 1):

Amigos esta fue mi solución, por si alguien tiene el mismo problema aquí esta:

```
include_once('../Verificacion/Conexion/Abrir_Conexion.php') ;

$consulta2 = "SELECT COUNT(id_pregunta) from preguntas";

$consultaFilas = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta2);
$count = mysqli_fetch_array($consultaFilas);
$count = $count[0]; 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM preguntas ORDER BY rand(" . time() . " * " . time() . ") LIMIT $count ";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);

include_once('../Verificacion/Conexion/Cerrar_Conexion.php') ;
```

Y después todo normal con el while. Hasta la próxima.:)